# How do I create a Hive External table from AVRO files writen using databricks?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, avro, databricks

The code below is how it was written into HDFS using scala. What is the HQL syntax to create a Hive table to query this data?

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
val path = "/user/myself/avrodata"
dataFrame.write.avro(path)
```

The examples I find require providing an **avro.schema.literal** to describe the schema or an **avro.schema.url** to the actual avro schema.

In the spark-shell all I would need to do to read this is:

```
scala> import com.databricks.spark.avro._
scala> val df = sqlContext.read.avro("/user/myself/avrodata")
scala> df.show()
```

Comment: A comment from the Spark-Avro source code states that *"Schema evolution is not supported yet. Here we only pick a single random sample file to **figure out the schema** of the whole dataset"* (https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/DefaultSource.scala).

Comment: Hive does not work that way, it requires **explicitly** the current AVRO schema at CREATE time. But the documentation (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe) states that there are two ways to do that: either link to an AVRO schema (available in a local file / in an URL), or simply list the columns as if it was a Text file and let Hive infer the AVRO schema from that SQL schema.

Answer (score 0):

So I cheated to get this to work. Basically I created a temporary table and used HQL to create and insert the data from the temp table. This method uses the metadata from the temporary table and creates the avro target table which I wanted to create and populate. If the data frame can create a temporary table from its schema, why could it not save the table as avro?

```
dataFrame.registerTempTable("my_tmp_table")
sqlContext.sql(s"create table ${schema}.${tableName} stored as avro as select * from ${tmptbl}")
```